# How to use d3.symbols with an ordinal scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

**TL;DR: How do I get a scaleOrdinal over the d3.symbols?**

I'm hoping to use [d3.symbols](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#symbols) for an ordinal scale, corresponding to a categorical attribute on some data.

> d3.symbols
>
> An array containing the set of all built-in symbol types: circle, cross, diamond, square, star, triangle, and wye. Useful for constructing the range of an ordinal scale should you wish to use a shape encoding for categorical data.

Here's what I thought would work:

```js
var svg = d3.select('#graph-container').append('svg').attr('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
var g = svg.append('g');

var data = [{type: 'a'}, {type: 'a'}, {type: 'a'}, {type: 'b'}, {type: 'b'}, {type: 'c'}];

var shape = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.symbols);

var s = g.selectAll('.symbol').data(data);

/* Does not render */
s.enter()
 .append('path')
 .attr('d', d => shape(d.type))
 .attr('x', (d, i) => i * 20)
 .attr('y', 50);

/* Sanity Check: Properly renders */
s.enter()
 .append('circle')
 .attr('r',7)
 .attr('cx', (d, i) => (i+1)*20)
 .attr('cy', 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph-container"></div>
```

(alternately see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkb3e6g8/3/)).

Unfortunately the above fails with:

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "[object Object]".
```

Clearly `shape(d.type)` is not returning a valid path. It's actually returning an object with a single function named draw, i.e. it looks like `{ draw: function() { ... } }`, which presumably refers to [this draw method](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#symbolType_draw). Calling that draw method doesn't yield a valid path either, though, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the symbol generator itself...

```
var symbol = d3.symbol();
```

... to which you'll pass the type:

```
s.enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', d => symbol.type(shape(d.type))())
    //etc...
```

Also, `<path>`s don't have `x` or `y` attributes.

Here is the code with those changes:

```js
var svg = d3.select('#graph-container').append('svg').attr('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
var g = svg.append('g');

var data = [{
  type: 'a'
}, {
  type: 'a'
}, {
  type: 'a'
}, {
  type: 'b'
}, {
  type: 'b'
}, {
  type: 'c'
}];

var shape = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.symbols);

var symbol = d3.symbol();

var s = g.selectAll('.symbol').data(data);

/* Does not render */
s.enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', d => symbol.type(shape(d.type))())
  .attr("transform", (_, i) => "translate(" + (20 + i * 20) + ",50)")
  .attr('fill', 'black');

/* Properly renders */
s.enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('r', 7)
  .attr('cx', (d, i) => (i + 1) * 20)
  .attr('cy', 100)
  .attr('fill', 'black');
```

```html
<div id="graph-container"></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: follow-up question: why do symbols.size() require such big sizes? What do those sizes refer to? There are hints that it might be the area of the symbol in the docs

Comment: Because it is indeed the area of the symbol. Unfortunately the API doesn't make it clear.